# Spaces containing a two variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Consider the function $f(x,t)$ where $(x,t)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$; I am looking for examples of such functions that are in $C\left([0,1],L_2([0,1],\mathbb{R})\right)$ with respect to either $t$ and $x$, but not in $C([0,1]\times[0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Can you be clearer? I can't tell what functions you want. And what does "$C\left([0,1],L_2([0,1],\mathbb{R})\right)$" mean?

Comment: It refers to the space that the map $t\mapsto f(\cdot,t)$ or $x\mapsto f(x,\cdot)$ belong to